# How does DNS work when it comes to addresses after slash?

Tags: networking, dns, ip-address, nameserver

Watching the DNS and SNI of my network adapter in Wireshark, all I see is domain names and sub-domain names, but nothing after the slash, like no mention of `example.com/page` or `twitter.com/mypage`

So, I'm wondering, how does an app or browser know which page to access after the forward slash?

Does the browser or app only need to know/query the IP address of the main domain or sub-domain and then it will simply add the slash after it? like `192.168.1.1/mypage` in case of Twitter for example?

I assume that works, but what if the address after the slash has a different IP address? like for example, `Twitter.com` is located at `192.168.1.1` but `Twitter.com/mypage` is located at `192.168.2.1`? Is it even mainstream to do this?

Lastly but the most important one, if DNS requests/responses and TLS SNI fields only contain subdomains and main domain of a website, does it mean for example my ISP won't know exactly which Twitter or Instagram pages I visit and only can see that I access Twitter.com and Instagram.com, as long as connection is HTTPS?

P.S. Please consider only usage of plain text DNS on port 53, no secure DNS like DoH or DoT at all.

**Update**: Reading [the comments under the selected answer](https://serverfault.com/a/173193/100013) on this Server Fault post answered my first question.

Comment: How do you figure that `Twitter.com` would resolve to `192.168.1.1` and `Twitter.com/mypage` to `192.168.2.1`?

Comment: @Albin now that I realize I was wrong about that, it doesn't make sense, but I'd assume using Ping or who-is lookup.

Comment: @zerogainer This is really simple to answer… Anything to the *left* of the slash is the hostname that is provided by DNS or could even be a regular IP address. Anything to the *right* of the slash refers to the application on that host. DNS has 100% nothing to do with anything to the *right* of the slash.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When it comes to handling http(s) requests, all that DNS does is convert the domain name to an IP address.   The web browser then connects to that IP address and asks for the resource (eg part after the slash) - no DNS involved.

Your contention that twitter.com is on 192.168.1.1 but twitter.com/mypage is on 192.168.2.1 is wrong.  From the web clients POV, both twitter.com and twitter.com/mypage exist on the same IP address.   It is possible for the server at twitter.com to act as a reverse proxy and fetch the final data from 192.168.2.1, but it will route the request through the secure connection established between the browser and 192.168.1.1.

DNS and SNI are barely related.  SNI is negotiated by the webserver and cares nothing about DNS (ignoring for the timebeing CAA records and the like, which are related but not SNI and are not ubiquitous).  In fact, take a website, move it to another IP address on another server - but make sure you port the certificates as well, modify your hosts file to point to the new IP address and your HTTPS site will work even when you have overridden the DNS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 2 answers posted, upvoted both, but could you answer the last part of the question as well before I can accept it please? from what I know so far, I assume the answer would be that my ISP will also see only domain and sub-domain names of websites I visit when using plain text DNS, but not the complete URL of the web pages, even after reading certificates CNs', is this correct assumption?
the reason I mentioned SNI and DNS together in the same context was because they both are elements that leak data to the listener on the wire, about which websites you are visiting.

Comment: Assuming the typical case (ie the ISP cant MITM the https through the use of a cert trusted by the client) the ISP can manipulate things so they can see the domain name but not the path, cookies or submitted form request data regardless of whether regular or DNS or DoH is used (or even if DNS is bypassed altogether).

Comment: @zerogainer An HTTP request can be conceptually broken up into two components: the envelope, and the payload. The envelope is TCP packet headers, and the payload is one or more TCP packet payloads. In HTTPS, the request's **method**, **path**, **headers**, and **body** -- which constitute the request's payload -- are all part of a single "text file" that is encrypted end-to-end. The **domain** is the only part that intervening routers can read, as it  is are part of the "envelope" an hence visible as TCP headers. The URL gets split into domain and path; path is part of the encrypted message.

Comment: And the domain is actually not there in text form; it's there as an IP address that intervening routers read and use to route the packet(s). [Here is an example of the "payload" portion of an HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#example)

Comment: @LukeGriffiths Your comments are at best misleading - If "envelope - which is not a standard concept for https AFAIK - is tcp packet headers", the domain is not part of the envelope.  In fact the domain name is not read by routers (but can be sniffed by them).  It is not a tcp header, and in fact QUIC and http/3 is not even use tcp.   The domain IS there in text form - this is a REQUIREMENT of SNI.

Comment: I like how @LukeGriffiths uses the concept of encapsulation, and this could be just a little enhanced to be correct. The textual domain name (that you entered into browser's address box) is the part of an "envelope" of the TLS session, if standard SNI is used. Accurately speaking, it appears in the first TLS message, ClientHello, during session establishment. The resolved IP or IPv6 address is in the "envelope" of each IP packet , obviously, regardless of what transport protocol they use, TCP, UDP or whatever.

Answer (score 39):

To add to the other answers: here's a quick dissection of a URL:

```
https://www.example.com:99/some/path?a=b&c=d#1223
```

- `https://` - the protocol aka the "language" that the browser will use to talk to the webserver.
- `www.example.com:99` - the address, which is further split into two parts:

  - `www.example.com` - the hostname aka the "domain name". The browser will convert this to an IP address before connecting
  - `:99` - the TCP port number that the browser will use to establish the network connection. This part is often omitted and then the browser uses the default port number for the selected protocol (`80` for `http`; `443` for `https`)
- `/some/path` and `?a=b&c=d` - the "path to the resource" and the "query string". The browser sends all of this together to the server, after it has established a connection (in the case of HTTPS that includes all TLS negotiations, so this gets sent encrypted). The browser doesn't modify this text apart from making sure that it doesn't contain illegal characters. It can really be anything and it's only a convention that the first part is a path to a "resource" and the second part is some sort of parameters. In reality you can send in almost anything and the server is free to do with it whatever it pleases.
- `#1223` - this is called "the fragment" and the browser does NOT send this to the server at all. This is 100% for client-side use. For example, if the URL results in an HTML page, the browser will try to find a HTML element with this ID and scroll to it. It can also be accessed via Javascript that runs in the browser (which can then do anything it wants with it). But it will never be sent anywhere.

So, as you can see, it is indeed only the domain part which gets looked up in the DNS system. And you can't use different IP addresses depending on the path.

Comment: The client can also use fragments for non-HTML content, such as PDF page numbers.

Comment: @OrangeDog Sure. The main point is - it never hits the network. I clarified the text a bit.

Comment: You might want to add that when using `https`, the path and query string is encrypted and not available to anybody but the client and server. And the answer is encrypted as well.

Comment: @StigHemmer - Changed the text so that it's hopefully clearer.

Comment: `www.example.com:99` is the _address;_ the _host_ is just the `www.example.com` part. It may (or may not) also help to clarify that an IP address does not include a port; a TCP address is an IP address plus a TCP port.

Comment: The `//` is more logically associated with the hostname part.  If you omit the protocol, there's no `:`, but you still need that introducer for a hostname.

Comment: Can we all stop with the nitpicking already?!  I'm aiming to get a fair enough intuitive understanding, not a full precise specification.

Comment: @MarkBooth - I apologize if I came across as rude. It was mean half-jokingly (hence the emoticon). I understand the sentiment, and thank you - but I also think that these suggested improvements are very minor, and are more likely to confuse novices (who are the main audience of this question anyway) than help them. I included the first few suggestions more to satisfy the commenters than to actually improve the answer, and I also felt like I could add these technicalities in a way that would be imperceivable if you aren't explicitly looking for them (aka "address" vs "host"). [contd]

Comment: @Vilx-: Yeah, it's up to you whether it's possible to dive into extra details without distracting from the key points.  If not, it's ok to just let the comments be footnotes, unless a moderator comes along and unhelpfully nukes them.  Other times, it's sometimes possible to adjust wording to convey the same simple idea in about as many words, but without implying (as many) incorrect ideas about the next level of complexity that you're not getting into.  For sure it's a tradeoff of what to leave as "useful lies to students", vs. when to make a footnote vs. when to expand in-place.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterCordes. That's what I was trying to say. I feel that starting to discuss the place and role of `//` and `:` in detail would be... pointless in the context of the question asked, and confusing for those who aren't experts already. Heck, I have worked professionally for 17 years in web development already, and have never needed to think about this. My goal with this answer isn't to be a complete specification/encyclopedia entry. It's to give an approachable explanation to beginners. :)

Comment: Sorry @Vilx- my eyes glazed right over the emoticon. I'm a bit old skool. *8')

Comment: I still think that useful information shouldn't only be in comments @PeterCordes, as I say on the site I moderate "Remember that comments may be tidied up (deleted) at any time". Of course if people really want an answer with all of the gory details, they can always submit one themselves. *8')

Comment: @MarkBooth: If not for that unfortunate policy that *all* comments are ephemeral, they would often work well as a good place for 3rd parties to add useful footnotes or corrections to answers.  And that is de-facto what happens if nobody gets around to finding a good way to edit the info into the post, as long as nobody comes along and deletes useful comments for no reason, especially highly-upvoted ones.

Comment: @Vilx-: All else equal, it is better to explain things in a way that's at least technically correct.  In the case of `https://` vs. putting the `//` with the hostname, yeah that's an interesting fact about how URLs work in terms of some components (like the protocol) being optional, but agreed that it would be clutter for this answer about how the hostname part is isolated from the rest.

Answer (score 19):

> what if the address after the slash has a different IP address?

It literally never has a different IP address. The HTTP URL syntax doesn't make that possible; it defines that *only* the part up to the slash is the "authority" (the server's domain name or IP address to connect to) – the same server is always responsible for all HTTP paths under its domain.

(The actual server can handle HTTP requests for different paths in whatever way it likes, e.g. it may serve some paths locally while proxying others to a different backend host, but that's all server-side logic that is invisible to clients.)

Answer (score 4):

There are many good answers here but they are frame challenges or explanations of the components of a URL. I'd recommend reading those before mine since mine is meant to expand upon those.

I am going to answer by accepting the premise of the question ("how could this happen?") but clarify what it actually means when it does.

It is not strictly true that "all that DNS does is convert the domain name to *an* IP address". It is possible for DNS to convert a domain name into *multiple* IP addresses. However, all of these IP addresses are meant to be equivalent to each other, and the selection of which of them to use (in all practical cases) has nothing to do with the other components of a URL.

Here is an example answer section from `dig microsoft.com` that I ran just now:

```
microsoft.com.      2838    IN  A   20.84.181.62
microsoft.com.      2838    IN  A   20.81.111.85
microsoft.com.      2838    IN  A   20.53.203.50
microsoft.com.      2838    IN  A   20.112.52.29
microsoft.com.      2838    IN  A   20.103.85.33
```

The parts in the middle aren't important, but for completeness, they are the TTL (`2838`), the address family (`IN`), and the record type (`A`).

When you request your browser or other tool to retrieve `https://microsoft.com/example` it will first do a DNS lookup for `microsoft.com` and then it will select *one* of the returned addresses to use. Very often, it will simply select the first in the list. The DNS server may also shuffle the addresses in the response, so that the first in the list is not the same one every time.

There are two main reasons why a server administrator may set up their DNS server to return more than one IP address for a particular domain name:

- Redundancy: if the HTTP server running at one of those addresses goes down, your browser may be able to handle this case by trying again with a different IP address; since they're all meant to be equivalent, you should get the same response back.
- Load balancing: one HTTP server may not be capable of serving all the requests that are received for the domain, and so multiple servers are used; again, they're all meant to be equivalent to one another, so you should get the same response regardless of which one you choose.

There are other ways to provide redundancy and load balancing though; for example, `dig google.com` right now is only returning one address for me, but I'm fairly certain Google isn't running their main page less robustly than Microsoft is. DNS is just one part of the process.

So, to connect back to the original question, it's entirely possible for `https://microsoft.com/` and `https://microsoft.com/example` to *appear* to resolve to two different IP addresses, but that's just because `microsoft.com` resolves to multiple IP addresses and a different one was picked the second time. If you kept doing this experiment a large number of times, you would see that both URLs can be resolved to any of the 5 addresses in the pool, since as stated by others it's only the domain name that matters.

Answer (score 2):

> So, I'm wondering, how does an app or browser know which page to access after the forward slash?

The browser sends that *path* and *query* information to the server whose address it found from the domain name. The server determines what it wishes to return for that.

When you ask your browser (or other user agent) to retrieve `http://www.example.com/foo/bar?a=1&b=2#baz`, it breaks down that URL into its components specified by standard [URL syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) and does the following:

1. Determine from the *scheme* portion, `http:`, that it is to use the HTTP protocol.
2. Determine from the `//` that what immediately follows it will be an *authority,* which in this case is just a server name: `www.example.com`. It will then look up the server name via DNS to get an IP address for it. You should see this DNS request and response in your Wireshark trace, if your filters allow it.
3. Since the authority had no port specification, the browser will assume the default port `80`, just as if you had typed `http://www.example.com:80/foo/bar`.
4. It will then connect to the server on that host and TCP port and send the *path* and *query* strings as part of the HTTP request. These will be in the *request line* that starts the request: `GET /foo/bar?a=1&b=2 HTTP/1.0`. (Note that it does *not* send the fragment.) You will see this if you examine the contents of the HTTP request in Wireshark.
5. The server will interpret the request as it wishes and return some sort of result.
6. If the result that comes back is an HTTP document, the browser will then look for an element with an `id="baz"` attribute (i.e., matching the fragment specified above) and scroll to it.

There are actually a few more subtleties in this process; for simplicity I've deliberately left out any mention of other schemes, other parts of the [HTTP request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HTTP/1.1_request_messages) beyond the *request line* (such as HTTP headers), any details about the HTTP response format, and what browsers might do with fragments when the response is not an HTML document.

> Lastly but the most important one, if DNS requests/responses and TLS SNI fields only contain subdomains and main domain of a website, does it mean for example my ISP won't know exactly which Twitter or Instagram pages I visit and only can see that I access Twitter.com and Instagram.com, as long as connection is HTTPS?

This is correct, so long as you've not installed any non-standard certificates in your browser that would allow a proxy or [transparent proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy) to proxy HTTPS connections via decryption and re-encryption.

In fact, for any given HTTPS request (or what they *assume* is an HTTPS request, since it goes to port 443 and uses TLS) all they can see is the IP address to which you connect, which in some cases might be a system hosting many different web sites (particularly if it's the address of a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) endpoint). That said, they will usually see your DNS requests as well, which are in cleartext, so they can certainly guess that if you looked up example.com to get 192.168.1.1 and you shortly after connect to port 443 on 192.168.1.1, you are connecting to example.com and not a different site that may also be served from that address.

Comment: Thank you, could you complete your answer by including answer to the last part of my question? oddly, there is only one comment in this whole page about it, which I specifically mentioned to be the most important one, just want to make sure there isn't any "subtleties" being left out for simplicity.

Comment: @zerogainer Sure! I've appended further explanation to the end of my answer above.

Comment: Thank you again, is this the right way to check for non-standard certificates? my browser Edge uses Windows cert store. `.\sigcheck.exe -tuv` and `.\sigcheck.exe -tv`. if there is better way to check for non-standard certificates please let me know. also why would a non-malicious proxy (proxy that's not malware) need to decrypt my HTTPS packets and re-encrypt it with its own certificate before sending them? I use proxies and they work without doing it. is there a special non-malicious use case for proxies to do that?

Comment: @zerogainer Unfortunately, I can't answer that particular question as I'm not a Windows expert. That is something you should probably post as a new question here or, better yet, in security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

DNS will only resolve the domain name `twitter.com` to an IP address, e.g. `192.168.1.1` (note that this is not actually Twitter's IP address but an address from an address block reserved for private networks).

The returned IP address may differ between multiple DNS requests due to e.g. DNS traffic management or simply a change in the DNS records associated with the domain.

Once your browser has resolved `twitter.com` to e.g. `192.168.1.1`, it will send an HTTP GET request to the server behind `192.168.1.1` asking for the resource `mypage` on the domain `twitter.com`:

```
GET /mypage HTTP/1.1
Host: twitter.com
```

Note that it would be possible for the server behind `192.168.1.1` to host multiple domains. If, for example, `example.com` was also hosted on `192.168.1.1`, an HTTP GET request for `example.com/mypage` would look like this:

```
GET /mypage HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

In summary, your browser finds out where to send the HTTP request using DNS and specifies within the request, which resource precisely it would like to get. The server, in turn, will know exactly which resource for which domain to serve given the information in the HTTP request.

For your last question, yes, using HTTPS the URL will be encrypted. However, the domain name part of the URL may be sent in clear text, depending on the TLS handshaking process in use. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted) for details.

So an attacker may be able to see you visited Twitter or Instagram but won't be able to tell which pages/profiles exactly.

Comment: Thank you, upvoted, since nowadays modern browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox) support ECH, I hope websites start implementing it too to complement the TLS v1.3 encryption, specially popular websites.

Answer (score 0):

You already received a good explanation of how DNS works in relation to your question. I'll answer the SNI part.

Short answer: Your ISP would only be able to see the hostname. SNI only contains the hostname your browser is trying to access. That is sent in plain text and is necessary for your browser to tell the web server which SSL certificate its requesting. The handshake is then made, and the connection secured before the full URL is sent.

Not as short answer (much more than you asked for but...)

SNI=Server Name Indication. It's part of the HTTPS TLS handshake process. When you want to connect to twitter.com, first the DNS is resolved for it. Then your browser sends a request to that IP address on port 443 (when using https://). Part of that request includes the SNI, if your browser supports it, which most do. The SNI only contains the domain name. If you typed https//www.twitter.com/bejrjoftj then the DNS lookup would resolve [www.twitter.com](http://www.twitter.com) and then include [www.twitter.com](http://www.twitter.com) as the SNI request. Note that "www." is actually a subdomain of the top-level domain name. A single IP can host many domains. Only HTTP and HTTPS access different resources based on the hostname requested. This is important because even though twitter.com and geocities.com might resolve to the same IP address, a web browser will receive different resources (the web page the server serves to you) based on the hostname requested, but that IP address can only host, for example, one SSH server on port 22. So, when you're accessing different websites with the same IP, that IP is only running one webserver, which decides which page to send you based on the SNI hostname. But that's all SNI is, is the hostname.

Apache HTTP Server and nginx both support virtual hosts. The server has a "default host" that it will serve if you, for example, used the IP address directly in your browser. This most often redirects to call a virtual host config. Virtual hosts aren't just the hostname though.

A virtual host can also be data to the right of the host name. For example, twitter.com and twitter.com/something/ could be two different virtual hosts. Since DNS only resolves the domain name/host name, twitter.com would resolve to the same IP no matter what the rest of the URL is. But the webserver does receive the full requested URL after the TLS handshake is made and the connection is encrypted. To reiterate, the purpose of SNI is to make sure the web server sends the correct SSL certificate to encrypt your connection, because if you're trying to access example.com and its IP address is the same as twitter.com, the server needs to make sure it sends the right certificate to your browser so your browser can verify that the certificate it received matches the host name it's trying to connect to.

Without the SNI, the server would have no way of knowing that you want the example.com virtual host from the server, not the twitter.com virtual host. And your browser needs to receive the example.com certificate to complete the handshake without any issues. The web server at that IP needs to have a virtual host entry for the hostname before it can define URL virtual hosts. example.com/ and example.com/page/ are not necessarily the same virtual host, even if they share the same certificate, if the config file has a virtual host defined for example.com/page/*. As for the reason why, you might end up at 192.168.2.1 for example.com/page while example.com/ is at 192.168.1.1, is because the virtual host can have a redirect defined. If it does, it will redirect your browser to the other IP. This is a software defined redirect and is defined by a result code, 300. A more commonly known result code is 404, which means the file requested doesn't exist. if the virtual host config includes a custom response page to send back to your browser whenever the server receives a 404 response back from URL you requested, it will send you that page every time you request a file that doesn't exist. The redirect response of 300 also includes a new URL, which tells your browser "Hey, you reached the example.com/page/ virtual host but sorry Mario, your princess is in another castle. You need to send that request to twitter.com/page/ instead." And then your browser says, "oh damn, okay, my bad." And then sends a request to whatever URL the server told it to go to. Thats how you end up getting redirected to a malicious URL when you tried accessing a seemingly innocent URL. But that redirect comes directly from the web server and not DNS. A DNS redirect is only when the DNS config has a CNAME record (normal IP address entries for IPV4 are A records). A CNAME record is an alias record. And an A or CNAME record is assigned to a host name. So, if page.example.com has a CNAME record in the example.com master record file with a value of "twitter.com", then the DNS client will be told to look up twitter.com to complete the request for page.example.com. a CNAME record is always a domain name and never an IP address. It tells your DNS client that page.example.com is just another name to use for twitter.com. this might be useful if you wanted to use page.example.com as another name for pagebook.com and you want the DNS client to follow the trail over to pagebook.com. this doesn't require you to run a web server with a virtual host set up for page.example.com. your DNS client will then look up pagebook.com and you'll get back whatever IP is assigned to pagebook.com instead.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use these exact domains? Otherwise your answer is well written, but this will probably get the answer deleted and you banned.

Answer (score -7):

DNS only involve the domain name. What you are looking at is a url. The domain name is the word immediately before the `.com` and can not have a period in it. So `something.domain.com/something…` simply `domain` is the domain name, which a then relate to dns in various manner. See URL’s for more.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Comment: I think I added that you have to correctly parse the url for the domain name. Basically he is confusing domain names, urls, and then DNS. I agree with accepted answer, major point is that DNS simply map a domain name to IP address. But also the issue is clearly that you must parse the domain name out of the url. Which does not care about slashes and stuff beyond.

Comment: This answer does not make it any clearer, AFAIC. It's also not entirely correct. The domain name in your example is "domain.com", not just "domain". It includes the top level domain (such as .com, .edu, .net or a country code top level domain such as .ca) or second level and top level domains if applicable (for example .ac.uk).

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1751499/92891 already explains sufficiently how to split up the URL.

Comment: I had to downvote because, though the general thrust of this answer is correct (the OP is confusing other parts of the URL with the domain name inside the URL), the details are quite incorrect. The `.com` is indeed part of the domain name; the domain name is not just the word before it. And domain names can indeed have periods in them, such as `www.example.com`. It may help for you to read up on the concept of an [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name), or _fully qualified domain name._

Comment: `something.domain.com` is also resolved by DNS and can resolve to a different IP than `domain.com`

Comment: Well seems the same thing is going on with some of you. There is an abstract thing called a domain name. And there are three independent web technologies which have their own views on it. DNS, urls, and like registered domain names.

Comment: And @gronodtaj I have doubts on that. Could a domain re-route a url, maybe. But to utilize that url, would require translating the domain name to its IP address.

Comment: Basically if I type, ‘something.domain.com’ I can trust that routes to the entity which owns and registers ‘domain’. There is no question.

Comment: So if I get an email from who ever, and a hypertext link with url ‘something.domain.com/stuff/…’ I can trust that the server entity which owns and registers ‘domain.com’ will be the server end point.

Comment: Yes, all subdomains of a domain are under control of the same people as the bare domain name, assuming they don't sell subdomains to other people.  But a DNS query for host records for foo.example.com can give different results than for example.com.  The same organization has control of that, but that doesn't mean they're the *same* host name (what a URL calls a domain).

Comment: “I can trust that the server entity which owns and registers `domain.com` will be the server end point.” No you can’t. Thus the downvotes here. Let me break down `something.domain.com`: The `.com` is the TLD (top level domain) connected to that hostname. The `domain.` is the domain name anyone can purchase for use with `.com` and the `something.` is a subdomain. The domain `domain.com` and `something.domain.com` can be 100% different hosts even if `domain.com` is owned  by one entity. As the owner of `domain.com` can assign `something.domain.com` to another service that would manage it.